# Cannot find "conan.conf" file in .conan2 folder

Tags: config, conan

[image]I am using conan 2.0 and in the .conan2.0 folder there is no conan.conf file. Is it removed from Conan2.0?

Comment: What does this have to do with python?

Answer (score 1):

Conan 2.0 no longer uses `conan.conf`, but only the new `global.conf`, which is already available too in 1.X. Also the legacy `conan.conf` used environment variables, while the new `conf` system uses `self.conf.get()` in recipes to get values, and `conan config list` can display the existing built-in configuration items (all of this available in 1.X)